# Where is the implementation of **prepareStatement** of **Connection interface** in java used in JDBC?

Tags: java, jdbc, interface, connection, prepared-statement

Where is the implementation of **prepareStatement** of **Connection interface** in java used in JDBC ?

```
String sql = "update people set firstname=? , lastname=? where id=?";

PreparedStatement preparedStatement = connection.prepareStatement(sql);
```

I couldn't find the implementation of connection interface, we directly call the methods of Connection interface but there must be class which would be implementing the Connection interface. If there is no class which implements the connection interface then how it works ?

Could anyone please explain me ?

Comment: each database has its own jdbc driver, and this driver has implementation

Comment: Actually, Connection interface is not limited to any particular vendor of database, its applicable for all databases , then how driver provides the implementation.

Comment: It seems to me you don't really understand how interfaces work...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> ...we directly call the methods of Connection interface but there must be class which would be implementing the Connection interface.

Yes, you're exactly right. The `Connection` interface is implemented by the JDBC provider library rather than in the JDK itself, because it's specific to the RDBMS you're using. So there's a MySQL `Connection` implementation, a SQL Server one, etc. You typically get a `Connection` from a `Driver` (directly or indirectly), which you get from a `DriverManager` (directly or indirectly), which you load from the JDBC driver jar for your RDBMS.

Comment: Thanks!!it depends on JDBC provider.